# Passing buffer memory mapped pointer to glTex(Sub)Image2D. Is texture upload asynchronous?

Tags: opengl, textures, buffer, opencl, dma

Suppose I map a buffer, with

`map_ptr = glMapBuffer (..)` (The target shouldn't matter, but let's say its `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER`)

Next I upload texture data with:

`glTexImage2D(..., map_ptr)`, passing map_ptr as my texture data. (I don't have a `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` bound)

Semantically, this involves copying the data from the buffer's data store to the texture object's data store, and the operation can be accomplished with a GPU DMA copy.

But what actually happens? Is the data copied entirely on the GPU, or does the CPU read and cache the mapped memory, and then write back to GPU at a separate GPU memory location? I.e. is the copy asynchronous, or does the CPU synchronously coordinate the copy, utilizing CPU cycles?

Is the answer to that implementation dependent? Does it depend on whether the OpenGL driver is intelligent enough to recognize the data pointer passed to `glTexImage2D` a GPU memory mapped pointer, and that a round-trip to the CPU is unnecessary? If so, how common is this feature in prevalent drivers today?

Also, what about the behaviour for an OpenCL buffer whose memory was mapped, i.e:

`map_ptr = clEnqueueMapBuffer(..)` (OpenCL buffer mapped memory)

and `map_ptr` was passed to `glTexImage2D`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do there is simply *undefined behavior* as per the [spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf).

> Pointer values returned by MapBufferRange may not be passed as parameter
>   values to GL commands. For example, they may not be used to specify array
>   pointers, or to specify or query pixel or texture image data; such
>   actions produce undefined results, although implementations may not
>   check for such behavior for performance reasons.

Let me quote from the [GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_buffer_object.txt) extension spec, which originally introduced buffer objects and mapping operations (emphasis mine):

> Are any GL commands disallowed when at least one buffer object is mapped?
>
> RESOLVED: NO.  In general, applications may use whatever GL
>   commands they wish when a buffer is mapped.  However, several
>   other restrictions on the application do apply: the
>   application must not attempt to source data out of, or sink 
>   data into, a currently mapped buffer.  **Furthermore, the 
>   application may not use the pointer returned by Map as an 
>   argument to a GL command.
>   (Note that this last restriction is unlikely to be enforced in
>   practice, but it violates reasonable expectations about how
>   the extension should be used, and it doesn't seem to be a very
>   interesting usage model anyhow.  Maps are for the user, not 
>   for the GL.)**

Comment: Thanks. So I guess the best way to accomplish the buffer to texture 'conversion' is simply to use a buffer texture (texture backed by a buffer)?

Comment: @Protongun: depends on the use case. A TBO is something completely different tah a texture, i.e. you can only directly fetch from it, but not use filters and wrap modes to actually sample from in. Internally, the data layout will be completely different. But if you want to use the contents of some buffer as a real texture, you can always just bind this buffer as `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` to source the `glTexImage*` data directly from it.